# Flutter Application Won't Verify App Link On Android

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, applinks, android-app-links

I'm trying to have my application use app links, but even though I went through all the steps and my `assetlinks.json` file is being requested, the disambiguation box still shows up. I tried the same steps with a native android app, and it worked without showing the box. Here is what I did:

1- Create a new flutter application.
2- Signed my application following the instructions on https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
3- Add the following to my activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="<example.come>" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I replaced `example.com` with my own domain, have https enabled, and serving `/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

Here is the content of `assetlinks.json`

```
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.example.app",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "hash_of_app_certificate"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I replaced `com.example.app` with my own, and changed the hash. I used this command to obtain the hash
`keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore path> -alias <key alias> -storepass <store password> -keypass <key password>`

4- Ran `flutter build apk` and installed the app on my device. I can tell that `assetlinks.json` has been requested from the server, but the selection box still shows up.

I tested my `assertlinks.json` on https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator and it says it is successful so whatever is wrong is on the app side.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Here is my `flutter doctor --verbose`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.746], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (7 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Moneer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Moneer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Moneer\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: follow with https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74784